# How to use Angular communicate to Android and ios phone to trigger that phone to make sound

Tags: angular, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, mobile, google-cloud-functions

Right now I'm developing tracking devices project to track mobile phone using Angular for a web app, firebase, cloud functions, and react-native. When a user lost their phone they can use a web app to find their phone by performing below step on my web app.

1. The select phone they want to find in a web app.
2. Click the button.
3. When a user clicked the button that phone will make a sound to let a user know where it is.

It's like find my app in ios devices but can use it in both OS.

My algorithm is something like this:

1. In firebase, I have a collection that collects mobile id, token, and isDeviceLost fields.
2. When a user clicked the button in a web app then the request will send to cloud functions to update isDeviceLost to be true which be false by default.
3. When isDeviceLost be true a function in react-native will trigger and make a sound on that device.

But the problem is I don't know how to create a function in react-native to make a sound on devices. So I decided to create this topic to get help from anybody who can help me solve this problem, Thank you

PS. If my algorithm doesn't the right way to do it you can help me fix it the right way.
PS2. If my English is bad I apologize. I'm still learning.